# Longitudinal Hierarchical Bayesian regression with JAGS

Tags: bayesian, panel-data, jags, openbugs

I'm completely new to JAGS/OpenBUGS so I would really appreciate a push in the right direction when it comes to specifying my model. I'm using an unbalanced longitudinal data that is compiled by 103 countries over 15 years where 12 years is picked in this case. The DV is the Gini coefficient, which shouldn't be modeled log-Normal but maybe rather Beta, although right now the focus is on just understanding how to compile the model in JAGS. I'm using a fixed effect model for the time being.

The data and code I'm running:

```
> head(x)
          Year     II2       II3       II4     ..... II24
1          1       2.956233  40.90458 4.475183       16.443553
8          1       1.257794  85.47378 2.395186       19.333433
19         1       4.139706 141.07899 2.544640       25.555404
37         1       2.233664  98.51313 3.902835       42.533333
49         1       2.879734  61.39000 1.471334       18.884444
71         1       3.381762  60.23783 3.432614       16.334222


> head(y)
        Year       II1
1         1     0.3240000
8         1     0.2576667
19        1     0.3132500
37        1     0.2700000
49        1     0.2744286
71        1     0.3250000

dim(x)
1224   23

length(y)
1224  

Time <- 12, N <- length(y$II1)#No. of Obs.

dat <- list(x=x, y=y, N=N, Time=Time, p=dim(x)[2]), 
inits <- funtion(){list(tau.1=1, tau.2=1, eta=1, alpha=0, beta1=0, beta2=0, beta3=0)}

model6 <- "model{
for(i in 1:N){for(t in 1:Time){
y[i,t]~dlnorm(mu[i,t],tau.1)
mu[i,t] <- inprod(x[i,t],beta[])+alpha[i]}
alpha[i]~dnorm(eta, tau.2)}

for (j in 1:p) {
b[j]~dnorm(0,0.001)
}

eta~dnorm(0, 0.0001)
tau.2~dgamma(0.01,0.01)
tau.1~dgamma(0.01,0.01)


 }"

reg.jags <- jags.model(textConnection(model), data=dat, inits=inits, n.chains=1, n.adapt=1000)
```

And I keep getting this runtime error:

```
Error in jags.model(textConnection(model), data = dat, inits =   inits,  : 
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 3.
Index out of range taking subset of  y
```

Any suggestions on what I should do differently would be hugely appreciated! I know there are 3 "tricks" you can apply to unbalanced data but I'm still a little bit confused about how all of this works, e.i. how JAGS read the data input.

Cheers

J

Comment: i don't see a `yy` anywhere in your model.  Are you sure this is the correct code and error message?
Also, I see an `xx` in your model, but you don't pass a variable named `xx` to jags in your data block, you pass it a variable named `x`.

Comment: @JacobSocolar: Ive edited the code a bit as I made som changes. I dont know if the changes were sensible, but at least I think the code is more clean cut and without typos. I still get the same compilation error though.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe `y` only has 2 columns. But `Time` is 12.  Where you have

```
y[i,t]~dlnorm(mu[i,t],tau.1)
```

inside a loop

```
for(t in 1:Time){
```

think about what happens when `t` goes up to 3 (on its way to `Time`=12).

You are asking JAGS to look at y[i,3], which doesn't exist.  Hence "Index out of range".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jacob. I figured it had to with that, however I don't know exactly in what format I should have my data in. What do you reckon I should do?

Comment: I'm assuming that in your data.frame `y`, `y$Year` takes integer values from 1 to 12.  You need: 

`y[i,t]~dlnorm(mu[i],tau.1)`;


`mu[i] <- inprod(x[i,y[1,i]],beta[])+alpha[i]}`

Note that you will still get a different `mu` for every observation `i`, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments @Jacob. I used your logic and made it run in the end. However Im not sure if it is correctly specified, Ill post the script of the beta regression when Im done with it.